# Deleting folder C# .net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, directory

I'm having trouble deleting a folder with all files in it.
I get this error:

```
Could not find a part of the path
```

What I'm trying to accomplish is, getting the relative path from the database, and then deleting that folder with all files in it.

Here is the code:

```
public IActionResult RemoveCar(string item)
        {
            var car = _context.CarModels.Where(x => x.Id.ToString() == item).FirstOrDefault();
            var pictures = _context.Pictures.Where(x => x.CarModelId.ToString() == item).ToList();
            if(pictures.Count() > 0 && pictures != null)
            {

                string parent = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(pictures[0].Path).Parent.ToString();
                string lastFolderName = Path.GetFileName(Path.GetDirectoryName(parent+"/"));
                string exactPath = Path.GetFullPath("/images/" + lastFolderName);
                System.IO.DirectoryInfo di = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(exactPath);
                // Delete this dir and all subdirs.
                try
                {
                    di.Delete(true);
                }
                catch (System.IO.IOException e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                }
                foreach (var pic in pictures)
                {
                    _context.Pictures.Remove(pic);
                }
            } 
            _context.CarModels.Remove(car);          
            return RedirectToAction("RemoveCar");
        }
```

Comment: Have you debugged and checked that `exactPath` contains the directory you expect? And that that directory does actually exist?

Comment: It does not, it just writes c:// before the relative path..

Comment: What about `Path.GetFullPath("images/" + lastFolderName)`?

Comment: Check where it starts to become the wrong path.
Not a solution, but a way to minify mistakes: use `Path.Combine`, when concatinating folders/folder and file.

Comment: Path.GetFullPath works, I do now get the correct path, but I still get the same error..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the first slash in this line is the problem,

```
string exactPath = Path.GetFullPath("/images/" + lastFolderName);
```

as it means 'move to the root'. Leave it out if you want a relative path.

Comment: Yes that works, I do now get the correct Path. But I get the same error :/

Comment: I saw what the problem was, it was that it didn't add in  wwwroot! So I changed the code to string exactPath = Path.GetFullPath("wwwroot/images/" + lastFolderName);